# Grepping out a block of text, regex

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

Given a large log file, what is the best way to grep a block of text?

```
text to be ignored
more text to be ignored
---                                 <---- start capture here
lots of 
text with separators like "---"
---
spanning 
multiple lines
---                                 <---- end capture here
text to be ignored
more text to be ignored
```

What is known?

- Max number of characters in line (55 but may be less)
- Number of lines in a block
- Separator (which may repeat itself)

What regular expression would match this block? Desired output: list of blocks of text.

Please assume Linux command line environment

Comment: Using what toolchain? Unix command line? (grep,sed,awk)

Comment: Yes please. Unix command line

Comment: so for the example text you list below, you need 1 or 2 or ?? blocks of output? What do you want to do with the `----`s? (Consider editing your question with this info). Good luck.

Comment: Updated question. I ultimately need to grab all the blocks ignoring all content outside of it.

Comment: Check out csplit(1) command.  Splits one file into multiple files based on a pattern match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several years ago I used this to split patches into hunks:

```
sed -e '$ {x;q}' -e '/@@/ !{H;d}' -e '/@@/ x' # note - i know sed better now
```

Replace `/@@/` with `/---/`.

To remove everything before first `'---'` and after last `'---'` add `-e '1,/---/d'` and remove the whole `-e '$ {x;q}'`.

Result would be like this:

```
sed -e '1,/---/d' -e '/---/ !{H;d}' -e x
```

Just tested it and it works with the given example.

Comment: Getting `sed: 1: "$ {d;q} ": extra characters at the end of q command`

Comment: I just copied the command and executed it. Different version of sed? I  have 4.2.1 here.

Comment: How do you find out sed version please?

Comment: Yes, tried that, getting an Illegal Version. I am running on MAC

Comment: try the new command - I removed the `q` (was actually useless)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22354/discussion-between-aragaer-and-jam)

Comment: Getting same error as before. What shell do you use? I am on `zsh`

Comment: I'm using bash. We should definitely move to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if (/^---/) { if (!start) start=NR; end=NR } next} FNR>=start && FNR<=end' file file
---                                 <---- start capture here
lots of
text with separators like "---"
---
spanning
multiple lines
---                                 <---- end capture here

$ awk 'NR==FNR {if (/^---/) { if (!start) start=NR; end=NR } next} FNR>start && FNR<end' file file
lots of
text with separators like "---"
---
spanning
multiple lines
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, you can use the following line. Note, however, that it will read the whole logfile into memory!

```
perl -0777 -lnE 'm{ ^--- .+ ^--- }xms and say $&' logfile
```